Show labels on the left and at the bottom
When Python draws a Sankey diagram, how to realize that the labels are displayed only on the left and at the bottom, especially for the multi-year land transfer matrix, displaying the land category at the leftmost, taking care to correspond one-to-one with the nodes, and displaying the year at the bottom, also corresponding one-to-one with the nodes.
First I followed the existing relevant code to achieve the following result:

# Generate a Sankey diagram for multiple time points
node_labels = []
for year in range(2000, 2022, 3):  # Add node labels for all time points
    node_labels += [f'Cropland {year}', f'Forest {year}', f'Shrubland {year}', f'Grassland {year}', 
                    f'Wetland {year}', f'Tundra {year}', f'Impervious surface {year}', 
                    f'Bare areas {year}', f'Water body {year}']

# Define the sources and targets for the Sankey diagram connections
sources = []
targets = []
values = []

# Populate the connections in the Sankey diagram
for idx, matrix in enumerate(transition_matrices):
    for i in range(len(matrix)):
        for j in range(len(matrix[i])):
            if matrix[i][j] > 0:  # Only connect categories with changes
                sources.append(i + idx * len(landcover_classes))  # Source node: for example, class 1 from 2000
                targets.append(j + (idx + 1) * len(landcover_classes))  # Target node: for example, class 1 in 2003
                values.append(matrix[i][j])  # Corresponding transition value

# Plot the Sankey diagram
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Sankey(
    node=dict(
        pad=15,
        thickness=20,
        line=dict(color="black", width=0.5),
        label=node_labels
    ),
    link=dict(
        source=sources,
        target=targets,
        value=values
    )
)])

fig.update_layout(title_text="Landcover Transition Over Multiple Time Periods", font_size=10)
fig.show()

Then I started to try to modify the Sankey diagram related code by myself hoping to realize that the labels are on the left side and at the bottom, but it failed, as shown in the figure:

Failure to realize the need for one-to-one correspondence
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np
import random

# Function to generate random colors
def generate_random_color():
    return f'rgba({random.randint(0, 255)}, {random.randint(0, 255)}, {random.randint(0, 255)}, 0.8)'

# Function to plot the continuous Sankey diagram
def plot_continuous_sankey(transition_matrices, year_pairs, labels):
    sources = []
    targets = []
    values = []
    all_labels = []
    colors = []

    num_classes = len(labels)
    
    # Create source, target, and value for each year pair
    for k, (start_year, end_year) in enumerate(year_pairs):
        matrix = transition_matrices[f'{start_year}-{end_year}']

        # Labels for the current year
        current_labels = [f'{label} {start_year}' for label in labels]
        next_labels = [f'{label} {end_year}' for label in labels]
        
        # Append current and next year's labels to the total label list
        all_labels.extend(current_labels)
        if k == len(year_pairs) - 1:  # Do not add next year’s labels for the last year pair
            all_labels.extend(next_labels)
        
        # Iterate over the transition matrix
        for i in range(matrix.shape[0]):
            for j in range(matrix.shape[1]):
                if matrix[i, j] > 0:
                    # Calculate source and target
                    sources.append(k * num_classes + i)  # Category for the start year
                    targets.append((k + 1) * num_classes + j)  # Category for the end year
                    values.append(matrix[i, j])  # Transition value

    # Generate random colors for each node
    for _ in all_labels:
        colors.append(generate_random_color())

    # Create Sankey diagram data, hide labels to avoid redundant display
    fig = go.Figure(go.Sankey(
        node=dict(
            pad=15,
            thickness=20,
            line=dict(color="black", width=0.5),
            label=[''] * len(all_labels),  # Hide node labels
            color=colors  # Set node colors
        ),
        link=dict(
            source=sources,
            target=targets,
            value=values,
            color="lightgray"  # Set link color
        )
    ))

    # Manually add class labels to ensure they match each node (vertical direction)
    for i, label in enumerate(labels):
        fig.add_annotation(
            x=-0.1,  # Position on the left
            y=1 - (i * (1.0 / num_classes) + 0.05),  # Calculate y-axis position based on the number of classes
            text=label,
            showarrow=False,
            xref="paper",
            yref="paper",
            font=dict(size=12, color="black")
        )

    # Manually add year labels to ensure they align with each column (horizontal direction)
    for k, (start_year, _) in enumerate(year_pairs):
        fig.add_annotation(
            x=(k + 0.5) / len(year_pairs),  # Calculate x-axis position based on the year pair, +0.5 to center with the column
            y=-0.1,  # Position at the bottom of the chart
            text=f'{start_year}',  # Display start year
            showarrow=False,
            xref="paper",
            yref="paper",
            font=dict(size=12, color="black")
        )

    # Update chart layout to ensure enough space on the left and bottom
    fig.update_layout(
        title_text="Continuous Landcover Transition Sankey Diagram",
        font_size=10,
        margin=dict(l=150, r=100, t=50, b=100)  # Adjust chart margins
    )

    fig.show()

# Create an empty dictionary to store transition matrices for each year pair
transition_matrices = {}
landcover_classes = ['Cropland', 'Forest', 'Grassland', 'Impervious surface', 'Bare areas', 'Water body']

# Define all year pairs
year_pairs = [
    (1985, 1990),
    (1990, 1995),
    (1995, 2000),
    (2000, 2005),
    (2005, 2010),
    (2010, 2015),
    (2015, 2020)
]

# Loop through the year pairs
for start_year, end_year in year_pairs:
    # Retrieve landcover data for start and end years
    start_landcover = globals()[f'landcover{start_year}']
    end_landcover = globals()[f'landcover{end_year}']
    
    # Calculate the landcover transition matrix
    translandcover = start_landcover.multiply(10).add(end_landcover)

    unique_values = translandcover.reduceRegion(
        reducer=ee.Reducer.frequencyHistogram(),
        geometry=roi.geometry(),
        scale=30,
        maxPixels=1e13
    ).get('remapped').getInfo()
    
    # Initialize transition matrix
    transition_matrix = np.zeros((len(landcover_classes), len(landcover_classes)), dtype=int)

    # Populate the transition matrix
    for key, value in unique_values.items():
        lc_start = int(key[0])  # Get the class of the start year
        lc_end = int(key[1])  # Get the class of the end year
        transition_matrix[lc_start - 1, lc_end - 1] = value

    # Store the transition matrix for the year pair in the dictionary
    transition_matrices[f'{start_year}-{end_year}'] = transition_matrix

# Call the function to plot the continuous Sankey diagram
plot_continuous_sankey(transition_matrices, year_pairs, landcover_classes)

